# Best way to block certain countries from access to website

Tags: javascript, liquid, web-traffic

I need to block certain on certain counties from accessing the website, and have made the following script below, but it does not block efficiently enough.

Unfortunately I do not have access to the .htaccess file or Apache config file through the CMS, so I need to solve it with  Javascript or similar coding.

Do you have any suggestion how to set it up or improve my script below?

```
<script>
var langcodes = new Array("zh", "default");
var langredirects = new Array("/lang/{module_pagename}", "DEFAULT");
var languageinfo = navigator.language ? navigator.language : navigator.userLanguage;
var gotodefault = 1;
function redirectpage(dest) {
    if (window.location.replace)
       window.location.replace(dest);
    else
        window.location = dest;
}

for (i = 0; i < langcodes.length - 1; i++) {
    if (languageinfo.substr(0, 2) == langcodes[i]) {
        redirectpage(langredirects[i]);
        gotodefault = 0;
        break;
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Users can get around this simply by turning off Javascript in their browsers.

Comment: Another way would be from PHP using a geocoding DB based on IP.

Comment: Yes Javascript really isn't a bulletproof solution.
I am using the CMS Adobe Business Catalyst. So I currently only have the possibility to use Javascript and Liquid. But the CMS runs on ASP, I'm working on getting full access to the .aspx files as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using PHP,then use an IP geolocation database (some are free) and $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] to get the visitor's IP address.

http://www.maxmind.com/app/geolitecity is a free (less accurate) version of a commercial one.

More details please [refer](https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-block-entire-countries-from-accessing-website/)

Comment: IMO, this tends to be an Apache's behavior, not a PHP one (so an Apache module or so)

Comment: .aspx alternative?

Comment: @Jones, php or aspx there should be way to get remote address for server side scripting language. Based on remote address, you can give message or redirect to some parent site if needed :)

Comment: Okay great. I'll try redirecting to the parent site and creating or custom landing page, which says "no access from your country" :)

Comment: @Jones Glad to help you..Please vote if my answer helps you

Comment: @mymotherland - sorry I totaly forgot while coding ;) thank you for the help :)